# C++ delete[] void* curiosity

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-allocation

I've got a rather simple, though large, system setup. It stores it's data in a `void*` array because the data it's storing could vary between `float` or `double` depending on how much accuracy is needed.

just doing `delete [] data` raises a `warning: deleting 'void*' is undefined [enabled by default]` using MinGW. And I've got another variable to tell me if `data` is a `float*` or a `double*`, but does it matter which I use?

In other words, could I use the fallowing code without worrying about memory-leak's, or other errors/damage not caught by the compiler?

```
double* d_data = new double[length];
data = (void*)d_data;
delete [] (float*)data;
```

Comment: The code you've shown very much invokes [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: IMHO - When you are casting you are usually doing something wrong. Use casting sparingly.

Comment: data = new unsigned char[length*sizeof(double)]; delete[] (unsigned char*)data;

Comment: @cppguy - Don't encourage him!

Comment: lol, I was on the last few lines of code anyway. the answers provided dont change anything other than satisfy a thirst for knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It certainly does matter; the pointer you use for `delete[]` must have the same type as the pointer that you allocated. So casting to `double*` is valid (but error-prone); casting to `float*` gives undefined behaviour.

[There is an exception for single objects (not arrays) of class types - it can be a pointer to a base class, *if* that base class has a virtual destructor. But that doesn't apply to primitive types like `double`, or to arrays.]

As for memory leaks: manual memory management *always* carries a danger of memory leaks, unless you're extremely careful never to do anything that might throw an exception. I highly recommend using [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) to manage all dynamic resources.

Comment: Thank you. My curiosity has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you might want to use a [union](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/).

Comment: I'm not trying to define a new data type. I'm familiar with Classes, Structures, Typedefs, Enums and Unions. I'm just curious about deleting allocated data. And if the "type" of the data actually matters or not when that type is basic, such as a float, int, double, char, or anything other fundimental data types. As all that really changes between them is how much data does each take, and how you interpret it. But what about deleting it?

Comment: In that case yeah, the pointer's data type determines the byte-size to delete. floats take 32-bits and doubles 64-bits. If you free it casted to float * then it'll delete elements * 4 bytes, if cast as double * then it'll delete elements * 8 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it matters (and casting to some other datatype is essentially as bad as leaving `void*`), because you're essentially losing/screwing up additional metadata (like the actual length). It might not necessarily crash though (e.g. you can use `delete data;` rather than `delete [] data;` as well, which would leak unless the compiler notices the mistake) as it's essentially undefined behavior (different compilers or versions might generate different results).

As Jorge suggested, you might just want to use a union for this, so two datatypes can share the same memory:

```
union my_union {
    double d_double;
    float d_float;
};
```

Depending on the compiler, this struct will usually be the same size as the biggest datatype inside (in this case (and on a 32 bit machine) probably 8 bytes for the double, 4 bytes for the float; so the total size would be 8 bytes, because these variables essentially overlap). Just keep in mind that you can't use this for some kind of automatic conversion.